# Hidden checkbox status "1" does not save in database in Django app

Tags: django, checkbox, hidden-field

In my app I have a `hidden` checkbox field which I intend to mark `checked` depending on some condition at runtime.

I have tried various ways to `hide` the checkbox:

In **forms.py** using:

`'checkbox_field': forms.HiddenInput()`

Or in the **template**:

Using `{{ checkbox_field.as_hidden }}`

And the `checkbox_field` is not displayed as expected.

However the problem I am facing is that the checkbox's status ('**1**' for `True`) is not saved on form submit. Whereas if I do not `hide` the checkbox the value is saved.

**As a work around** (on the other hand), if I keep the checkbox **visible**, mark it `True` and then set it as `hidden` (at runtime), the value is saved.

It's obvious I am getting something wrong here.

**My question is:**

How may I keep the checkbox hidden and at the same time be able to save its `status` in the database?

Comment: Where do you see that the value of the checkbox is '1'? Because normally a checkbox sent has the value 'on'

Comment: Can you share the code of your form?

Comment: In the corresponding field of the table in database. I am only using a simple Django `ModelForm`.

Comment: There is a problem somewhere, so share model, view and HTML please...

Comment: Sorry. Getting some weird message: `There are too many pending edits on Stack Overflow. Please try again later.`